# Use of sequences in 'shift' with conditions

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have a data.table with a list of days `a` (there's no need to worry about weekends/weekdays):

```
dt <- data.table(a = 1:10)
```

If I want to get the day before a day which satisfies given condition (i.e. the day before day 4), I can simply use

```
dt[shift(a == 4, type = "lead")]
```

However, if I want the two days before day 4, I can't use

```
dt[any(shift(a == 4, 1:2, type = "lead"))]
```

since that raises an error.

Indeed, the only way I've managed to do it is with

```
dt[apply(apply(dt[, shift(a,
                          1:2,
                          type = "lead")],
               1, `==`, 4),
         2, any) == TRUE]
```

Which is so unelegant it can't be right.

So, how'd this be done?

To make things worse, my final objective is to get the X days before multiple days. So I'd hoped to do something like `dt[any(shift(a %in% c(4, 10), 1:2, type = "lead"))]`, but it (and similar attempts such as putting the `%in` test out of the `shift`) obviously doesn't work.

To be clear, with the data.table above, if I wanted the two days before days 4 and 10, I'd expect the output to be:

```
     a
 1:  2
 2:  3
 3:  8
 4:  9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is `Reduce`.  The `shift` output would be a `list` of columns which can `Reduce`d to a single logical `vector`

```
dt[dt[, Reduce(`|`, shift(a==4, 1:2, type="lead"))]]
#   a
#1: 2
#2: 3
```

NOTE: This is vectorized as well

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pmax`, which is the parallel version of `any`:

```
dt[do.call(pmax, shift(a==4, 1:2, type="lead")) == 1L]

   a
1: 2
2: 3
```

To see why this works, you can inspect what your `shift` is returning like...

```
with(dt, shift(a==4, 1:2, type="lead"))

[[1]]
 [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA

[[2]]
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA    NA
```

That is, it is a vector of vectors, while `any` expects to work with one vector at a time. While I think `pmax` is the best way to go, you can also `transpose` the vector of vectors and then use `any`:

```
dt[ sapply(FUN = any, 
  transpose(shift(a==4, 1:2, type="lead"))
) ]

   a
1: 2
2: 3
```

Generally, `sapply`/`lapply`/`vapply` are better than `apply` unless you are working with a matrix already.

Comment: @chinsoon12 No, just working somewhere new and don't want to use my usual credentials on my work computer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized way to do this -

```
get_prev_days <- function(days, n) {
  ind <- rep(days, each = n) - rep(n:1, length(days))
  ind[ind > 0] # removes -ve indices when n > min(days)
}

dt <- data.table(a = 1:10)

dt[get_prev_days(days = c(4, 10), n = 2), ]

   a
1: 2
2: 3
3: 8
4: 9
```